# Create a column based on a max value among several columns with the corresponding column name (instead of column value)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe named df_test that shows the score for each product per region. I want to create a column calls "highest score product" that shows the corresponding product name with highest score per region.

I used the max() function to get the highest product score, but the desired output should show the product name instead of score in the "highest score product" column.

I tried df_test.idxmax(axis="columns") but I got error probably due to empty value. However, these empty values cannot be filled NA with 0 because all data value have to be remained as is (including np.nan and None) for special treatment in the downstream process.

What would be a good way to achieve this? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

region= 'region'
product1 = 'product1'
product2 = 'product2'
product3 = 'product3'
product4 = 'product4'
product5 = 'product5'

list_reg = ['region1', 'region2','region3','region4','region5','region6']
list_score1 = [100, 250, 350, 555,999999, 200000]
list_score2 = [41, 111, 12.14,16.18,np.nan,200003]
list_score3 = [7.04, 2.09, 11.14,2000320,22.17,np.nan]
list_score4 = [236,249,400,0.56,359,122]
list_score5 = [None, 1.33, 2.54, 1, 0.9, 3.2]

df_test = pd.DataFrame({region: list_reg,
                        product1: list_score1,   
                        product2: list_score2, 
                        product3: list_score3, 
                        product4: list_score4, 
                        product5: list_score5})


col = [product1,product2,product3,product4,product5]
df_test['highest score product'] = df_test[col].max(axis=1)
df_test
```

output as below -
[image]

desired output as below -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df_test["highest score product"] = df_test.loc[:, "product1":"product5"].idxmax(axis=1)
print(df_test)
```

Prints:

```
    region  product1   product2    product3  product4  product5 highest score product
0  region1       100      41.00        7.04    236.00       NaN              product4
1  region2       250     111.00        2.09    249.00      1.33              product1
2  region3       350      12.14       11.14    400.00      2.54              product4
3  region4       555      16.18  2000320.00      0.56      1.00              product3
4  region5    999999        NaN       22.17    359.00      0.90              product1
5  region6    200000  200003.00         NaN    122.00      3.20              product2
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej for this solution. In my real dataset, those products have actual names (not product1, 2, 3, etc). In this case, how do I do this efficiently? Or at least how to replace the "product1":"product5" part?

Comment: @user032020 You have specified `col` list in your code. In that case you can use `df_test.loc[:, col].idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: @user032020 Or if `Region` is first column and then product columns, you can do `df_test.loc[:, df_test.columns[1:]].idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks! The col approach works better..